Export ArcMap annotations for use in QGIS
I have a project in ArcMap that contains annotations. Now I would like to open them in QGIS. Is there a way to export annotations in ArcMap in such a way that they can be opened in QGIS (via SLYR or another plugin (?)?
I saved the annotation labels as .lyr and tried to open them in QGIS via SLYR. However, the error message appears:
slyr_community.parser.exceptions.UnknownClsidException: Unknown CLSID: 34b2ef83-f4ac-11d1-a245-80009b6f22b

Maybe someone knows this error message or CLSID, unfortunately I have not found anything about it on the internet.

Are the annotations in the View Properties hence only in that project or in a dataset like a file geodatabase annnotation layer?  If the latter add it to a QGIS project.  Due to limitations in the ESRI API you may get polygons instead of labels, but you can make the polygon invisible and the label them using the best Placement option.  I recall the attribute table will have a field showing font size and you can use the "cabinet" option  to use that in the different labels.

At a guess... it looks like .lyr files are legacy now. There's a modern version .lyrx which is xml based. Have you tried saving as that?
Doco link https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/layerfile.htm#:~:text=The%20ArcGIS%20Pro%20application%20can,lyrx%20file%20types.

Thanks for the comments! I also exported the layers yesterday as a feature class to a GDB and then imported it into QGIS. I got exactly what you mean: polygons instead of layers. I then adjusted these manually, but the alignment problem remains. Unfortunately, I also have a huge data set for my municipal administration, so it would take a very long time to set up all the labels correctly and consistently.

I haven't tried .lyrx yet, as I use the SLYR plugin for importing into QGIS. The free version can only read .lyr data, for .lyrx I would have to buy the paid license. If everything does not work, there will also be this way.
Maybe in the future there will also be a plugin for the professional import of annotations, who knows... :)
